# How do I create a table with composite primary keys in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

If I have a data set like

```
("group_1" , 1 , other, columns),
("group_1" , 2 , other, columns),
("group_1" , 3 , other, columns),
("group_2" , 1 , other, columns),
("group_2" , 2 , other, columns),
("group_3" , 1 , other, columns),
("group_3" , 2 , other, columns),
```

And there are hundreds of thousands of these groups and I want to make queries like:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE group = 'group_1);
```

How should I declare such a table? Considering there is no auto_increment function in Cassandra and I think I should define `uuid()` column as well in combined with `group` column to make a composite primary as follows like:

```
("group_1" , uuid , other, columns),
("group_1" , uuid , other, columns),
("group_1" , uuid , other, columns),
("group_2" , uuid , other, columns),
("group_2" , uuid , other, columns),
("group_3" , uuid , other, columns),
("group_3" , uuid , other, columns),
```

What I know is that I can do

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( group TEXT, id TEXT, ..., PRIMARY KEY((group, id)) );
```

But this way I should use `ALLOW FILTERING` in my queries like below and I guess this is not a good approach.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE group = 'group_1' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I am just wondering what is the best way of handling this situation?

`EDIT`: Upon more detail request in answer from @Erick Ramirez, the real data I am trying to design a database for is like the tag section in StackOveflow. One user creates a new tag and other users will use the tag in their questions. Then somebody else can filter the questions based on tags and see the only questions they have `Cassandra` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake that you made is that you started thinking about it from the perspective of your dataset and this is a common mistake in Cassandra.

In Cassandra data modelling, you should always start by listing the application queries THEN design a table for EVERY app query.

If you need to query by group then you should partition by that column. And it looks like each group has multiple rows so you need to cluster by that [`int`] column. For simplicity, I'll call the clustering column (clustering key) `ck`.

Here is a what a possible schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE somedata_by_group (
    group text,
    ck int,
    somecolumn text,
    anothercolumn text,
    PRIMARY KEY (group, ck)
)
```

You can then query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM somedata_by_group
  WHERE group = ?
```

It is not necessary to use the `ALLOW FILTERING` clause.

For future reference, you would get more responses if you use real data and describe your use case. It is difficult to provide a good answer to your question since it lacks details. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also added an `EDIT` part at the end of my question about what is the real case I am trying to resolve.